# Hiding a script name in a URL with web.py and mod_rewrite

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web.py

I am using web.py for my project and I would like to hide the "index.py" script name from the URL. I am using the following .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/.*)+index.py/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.py/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

It works fine, except for redirects invoked with web.seeother(). For such redirects, it still shows index.py in the URL.

As suggested in several posts, I have tried setting SCRIPT_NAME / REAL_SCRIPT_NAME environment variables to empty in the beginning of my script, but it did not help.

```
os.environ["SCRIPT_NAME"] = ""
os.environ["REAL_SCRIPT_NAME"] = ""
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` won't modify links you serve, only incoming requests so I don't think you can do what you want using it.

Comment: Could you post the apache2 config file you are using as well?

Comment: Found the root of the problem. It was due the expired browser cache, while the configuration was just fine. Thanks for your help.